# Importing Symfony project error

Tags: php, symfony, import, bootstrapping

I am new to symfony framework. I have download a file project from  https://github.com/thujohn/Jobeet and I try to open this url:
 http://localhost/job/web/app_dev.php/ and it gives this message:

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\job\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\job\web\app_dev.php on line 22
```

Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

```
1   0.0011  244064  {main}( )   ..\app_dev.php:0

( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\job\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\job\web\app_dev.php on line 22
```

Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

```
1   0.0011  244064  {main}( )   ..\app_dev.php:0
```

please tell me what should I do .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure, but i think you need

```
$ composer install
$ php app/console cache:clear
```

Read [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html), it will help you install Symfony2.